# How to send HTTP chunked response to emulate a video stream using Proxygen and Folly?

Tags: facebook, http, video-streaming, chunked-encoding, folly

I am writing a HTTP video streaming server based on Facebooks Proxygen. There is no seeking planned. Using the `proxygen::ResponseBuilder` I am abled to send chunks of a webm encoded video as HTTP response, i.e. chunked transfer encoding is working. My problem is, that Proxygen waits for `proxygen::ResponseBuilder::sendWithEOM()` before it even sends the response headers. I would like it to actually send the data asap after each call to `proxygen::ResponseBuilder::send()`.

I tried to run the ResponseBuilder calls from a lambda executed from the EventBaseThread using `evb->runInLoop()` and `evb->runInEventBaseThread()`

```
using namespace folly;
using namespace proxygen;

std::thread t([&](){
    EventBase* evb = EventBaseManager::get()->getExistingEventBase();    
    // send headers ...
    while ( chunks avail. ) {
        //...
        evb->runInLoop([&](){
            ResponseBuilder(downstream_)
                     .body(std::move(chunk))
                     .send();
        });
        //... 
    }
    // sendWithEOM ...
});
t.detach();
```

This code is called from the `onRequest()` method of my `RequestHandler`. I tried to call `ResponseBuilder::send()` without wrapping it into `evb->runInLoop()`, but Proxygen v0.25.0 with Folly v0.42.0 is prohibiting calls to `ResponseBuilder::send()` from another thread using an assert. I removed this assert from here: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/v0.42.0/folly/io/async/EventBase.cpp#L491.

Now the emulated streaming is working, but it's crashing, if there are  parallel requests. I guess it was not meant to be used like this, that's what the assert is for. But maybe anyone knows how to use the Proxygen infrastructure properly for my usecase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's got the same issue. I got it working with something like this.

```
folly::EventBase* eventBase = folly::EventBaseManager::get()->getExistingEventBase();
thread t([&, eventBase]() {
    while( chunks exist ) {
        auto chunk = getChunk();    
        eventBase->runInEventBaseThread([&, chunk=chunk]() mutable {
            ResponseBuilder(downstream_).body(move(chunk)).send();
        });
    }
});
// sendWithEOM ...
t.detach();
```

Comment: Since I need more reputation to give +1, thank you for the answer, solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace folly;
using namespace proxygen;

//Get Event Base in worker thread and pass it to new thread. If you call this inside new thread then you won't get worker thread's event base.
EventBase* evb = EventBaseManager::get()->getExistingEventBase();   
std::thread t([&, evb](){

// send headers ...
while ( chunks avail. ) {
    //...
    evb->runInLoop([&](){
        ResponseBuilder(downstream_)
                 .body(std::move(chunk))
                 .send();
    });
    //... 
}
// sendWithEOM ...
});
t.detach();
```

So no need to comment assertion in EventBase source.